# What is the order of

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

What is the order of the following:
$$\frac{(33x^{7}+6)(x^{2}+3)}{\sqrt{x^3+7x^2-x+5}}$$

Would it be $$\Theta (x^{\frac{17}{2}})$$

Comment: As $x\rightarrow \infty$? Or as $x\rightarrow 0$? Also, how can you show us how you got $17/2$?

Comment: @par : As x goes to infinity. I got it by taking the difference between the degree of the numerator, which is 9 and denominator, which is 1/2

Comment: I believe that is correct, then.

Comment: Just make the difference $9-\frac 32$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  As $x \to \infty$, the numerator $\sim 33 x^9$, but the denominator $\sim x^{3/2}$ (not $x^{1/2}$), so this is $\Theta\left( x^{9-3/2}\right) = \Theta\left(x^{15/2}\right)$